# How to convert image URLs in Drupal node's fields while rendering?

Tags: 7, views, nodes, uri, media

I have developed a new CCK module using [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com) where users can drag and upload images using native HTML5 apis. Since, I do not know how to drag images directly inside CKEditor, what I am doing is that after images are uploaded using plupload's jQuery widget, I show an image instead of a filename from where users can drag that image inside a CKEditor. Its a 2-step drag-n-drop process.

Now, when I drag & drop images into a CKEditor using Chrome, CKEditor generates following code

```
<p>
    <img src="http://myportal/sites/myportal/files/plupload/p15sjkcj2c1o3koe3hsp19761ep14.jpg" /></p>
```

When I do similar action using Firefox/Safari, CKEditor generates following code

```
<p>
    <img src="../../sites/myportal/files/plupload/p15sjle1js11r5289aibk0m1n7q3.jpg" /></p>
```

Problem is depending on from where I am viewing the node (views, panel etc), images sometimes shows up and sometime not, because they point to location starting with ../../ and not with http://myportal/.

So, how do I make sure that when Drupal is generating node's view, "../../sites/myportal/files/plupload/p15sjle1js11r5289aibk0m1n7q3.jpg" is expanded or converted to "http://myportal/sites/myportal/files/plupload/p15sjkcj2c1o3koe3hsp19761ep14.jpg"

One way I  can do this is using jQuery to find all `<img>` tags with a word 'plupload' in their src attribute , and then changing that attribute with full URL. But, it will slow down display a lot. Any other ideas using Drupal module or custom coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably accomplish that with a custom filter involving a regular expression using either [Flexfilter](http://drupal.org/project/flexifilter) or [Custom filter](http://drupal.org/project/customfilter).